# Undefined function

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and I need some advice on why I am getting an error message that states `this.node` is `undefined`.

What I have is a app built on `ExtJs` using the MVC architect. In my Controller, I have developed a layout containing a tree and a grid. In the tree, there are parent nodes that can be added by clicking a New button and its method works perfectly.

However the method that will update a record by `id` from my database using the same form that is used to insert a record is generating a message stating the `this.node` is `undefined`.

This is my code for the `Edit handler`:

```
handleBtnEdit: function (btn, ev, eOpts) {
    console.log(this);
    var id = parseInt(this.node.get("id")), rec = this.app.getStore("ProblemRequirements").getById(id);
    this.launchForm(rec);
}, 
handleBtnAdd: function (btn, ev, eOpts) {
    var rec = Ext.create("SPOT.model.ProblemRequirement");
    this.launchForm(rec);
}, 
handleBtnSave: function (btn, eOpts) {
    var win = btn.up("window"), pnl = win.down("form"), frm = pnl.getForm(), grid = pnl.down("grid"), store = grid.getStore(), rec = frm.getRecord();
    if (frm.isValid()) {
        rec.set(frm.getValues());
        win.setLoading("Saving, please wait...");
        rec.save({
            callback : function(rec, operation) {
                if (operation.success) {
                    win.close();
                    this.getStore("ProblemRequirements").load();
                    this.playMsg("Problem requirement successfully " + (operation.action === "update" ? "updated" : "created" ) + ".");
                } else {
                    win.setLoading(false);
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Error!", operation.error[0].ERROR);
                }
            },
            scope : this
        });
    }
}, 
launchForm: function (rec) {
    Ext.create("Ext.window.Window", {
        buttons : [{
            handler : this.handleBtnSave,
            scope : this,
            text : "Save"
        }, {
            handler : this.handleBtnCancel,
            scope : this,
            text : "Cancel"
        }],
        closable : false,
        draggable : false,
        iconCls : (rec.phantom ? "icon-add" : "icon-edit"),
        items : [{
            listeners : {
                afterrender : {
                    fn : function(pnl, eOpts) {
                        pnl.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
                    },
                    scope : rec
                }
            },
            xtype : "problemrequirementForm"
        }],

        modal : true,
        resizable : false,
        title : (rec.phantom ? "Create a New" : "Edit") + " Problem Requirement",
        width : 500
    }).show();
},
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.getAttribute("id")` ?

Comment: adding the getAttribute didn't change anything.

Comment: where would i place this call and what results should i look to see?

Comment: Add `alert(this);` as the first line in the function. This should alert which kind of element you are looking at.

Comment: Ok, can you try `console.log(this)` and tell what you see in the console.

Comment: TypeError: this.node is undefined

Comment: Just `this`, not `this.node`.

Comment: no, it says TypeError: this.node is undefined var id = parseInt(this.node.get("id")),

Comment: Instead of `alert(this)`, please add `console.log(this);` as the first line in the function. This will log the data to the JS log, check the log and tell me what you see.

Comment: @ATOzTOA i placed console.log(this) in my function and it returned the same TypeError message. I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: So, you are saying `alert(this);` worked, but `console.log(this);` failed? That is not possible, are you adding `console.log` line before or after the `var id =...` line?

Comment: this is what i have right now. [console.log(this);
  var id = parseInt(this.node.get("id")),
      rec = this.app.getStore("ProblemRequirements").getById(id);
  
  this.launchForm(rec);]

Comment: Please change it to `console.log(this); var id = parseInt(this.node.get("id")), rec = this.app.getStore("ProblemRequirements").getById(id); this.launchForm(rec);`

Comment: Please share the code which you use to add parent nodes, which you say works fine.

Comment: okay, this is the Handle for the Add functions         handleBtnAdd: funtion (btn, ev, eOpts) {
   var rec = Ext.create("SPOT.model.ProblemRequirement");
   this.launchForm(rec);
 },

Comment: I could send you the handleBtnSave and launchForm code, if you think that would help, but it is to lengthy to place in a comment.

Comment: You can update your question with the code. Also, have you got the `console.log()` output?

Comment: ok, so I placed the add, edit, save and form methods in for you. as far as the console.log(), it only states what i have already placed in out comment about the TypeError

Comment: I have given a comment after you posted your code as comment. Try `console.log(this);`. Note, it is NOT `this.node`.

Comment: Thank you, but as I already stated, I DO have it written as you suggested console.log(this); and the Console Log Error message is TypeError: this.node is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `handleBtnEdit` with this version and copy paste your console log.

```
handleBtnEdit: function (btn, ev, eOpts) {
    console.log("-- Start of handleBtnEdit --");

    console.log(btn);
    console.log("-- 1 --");

    console.log(ev);
    console.log("-- 2 --");

    console.log(this);
    console.log("-- 3 --");

    console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
    console.log("-- 4 --");

    console.log(this.node);
    console.log("-- 5 --");

    //var id = parseInt(this.node.get("id"));
    //var rec = this.app.getStore("ProblemRequirements").getById(id);
    //this.launchForm(rec);
},
```

Also, add the code which calls `handleBtnEdit`.

**Update**

Console log:

```
-- Start of handleBtnEdit -- 
btn :: Object { disabled= false , iconCls= "icon-edit" , id= "btn-edit" , more...} 
-- 1 -- 
ev :: Object { browserEvent=Event click, type= "click" , button= 0 , more...} 
-- 2 -- 
this :: Object { application={...}, id= "ProblemRequirements" , hasListeners={...}, more...} 
-- 3 --
```

So, the argument passed in a button with `id= "btn-edit"`.
`this` seems to be an `Object` with `id= "ProblemRequirements"`.

**Update 2**

As there is no node inside `this` and the `id` of this doesn't seem to be one we need, try this code:

```
handleBtnEdit: function (btn, ev, eOpts) {
    var id = parseInt(btn.id);
    var rec = this.application.getStore("ProblemRequirements").getById(id);
    this.launchForm(rec);
},
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers.  If you have additional ideas, update your first answer accordingly.

Comment: -- Start of handleBtnEdit --

Proble...1266556 (line 202)
Object { disabled=

false

, iconCls=

"icon-edit"

, id=

"btn-edit"

, more...}
Proble...1266556 (line 204)

-- 1 --

Proble...1266556 (line 205)
Object { browserEvent=Event click, type=

"click"

, button=

0

, more...}
Proble...1266556 (line 207)

-- 2 --

Proble...1266556 (line 208)
Object { application={...}, id=

"ProblemRequirements"

, hasListeners={...}, more...}
Proble...1266556 (line 210)

-- 3 --

Comment: Can you copy paste the complete console log here?

Comment: -- Start of handleBtnEdit --

Proble...1266556 (line 202)
Object { disabled=

false

, iconCls=

"icon-edit"

, id=

"btn-edit"

, more...}
Proble...1266556 (line 204)

-- 1 --

Proble...1266556 (line 205)
Object { browserEvent=Event click, type=

"click"

, button=

0

, more...}
Proble...1266556 (line 207)

-- 2 --

Proble...1266556 (line 208)
Object { application={...}, id=

"ProblemRequirements"

, hasListeners={...}, more...}
Proble...1266556 (line 210)

-- 3 --

Comment: Ok, now you have to click on the triangle to the left of the line `Object { application={...}, id`, the one above `-- 3 --`. This will give you the whole tree of `this`. Check if you see a `node` in there. Also, instead of `console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));`, try `console.log(this.id);`.

Comment: there is no node in the log above --3-- this is the new log after changing the console.log(this.getAttribute("id")); with console.log(this.id);

Comment: Object { application={...}, id=

"ProblemRequirements"

, hasListeners={...}, more...}
Proble...2617024 (line 210)

-- 3 --

Proble...2617024 (line 211)

ProblemRequirements

Proble...2617024 (line 213)

-- 4 --

Proble...2617024 (line 214)

undefined

Proble...2617024 (line 216)

-- 5 --

Comment: getting closer, now the log reads TypeError: this.app is undefined

var rec = this.app.getStore("ProblemRequirements").getById(id);

Comment: Try `this.application.getStore("ProblemRequirements").getById(id);`. Also try `console.log(this.application);`.

Comment: that looks good, but still no load of launchForm. the rec is null in the launchForm where the line reads                                   iconCls: (rec.phantom ? "icon-add" : "icon-edit"),

Comment: i am now unable to Add a new record with the changes that have been added to the handleBtnEdit method.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I was able to figure out what was wrong. the handleBtnEdit needed to be configured this way.  handleBtnEdit: function (btn, ev, eOpts) {
     var node = Ext.getCmp("pnl-problemrequirement-tree").getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
       rec = this.getStore("ProblemRequirements").getById(parseInt(node.get("id")));
     this.launchForm(rec);
 },

Answer (score 2):

`node` is out of scope.  You need to determine what scope `node` is defined in and reference it appropriately, or you need to make it globally visible, or you need to define it in the local (`this`) scope.

Consider this contrived example:

```
// Set global window var 'a'
window.a = 'foo';

// Create an object which has it's own scope:
var x = {
    a:'bar',

    speak:function(scope){
        console.log(scope['a']);
    }
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
// Have x report on its own scope (in function 'speak' this is the same
// as doing: console.log(this['a'])
x.speak(x);

> bar

// Set the scope to the (global) 'window' scope
x.speak(window);

> foo
```

Now if we redefine `x` so that it has no member `a`, and try the same thing:

```
var x = {
    speak:function(scope){
        console.log(scope['a']);
    }
};

x.speak(window);

> foo

x.speak(x);

> undefined
```

In the last example, there is no `a` within scope of the `x` object, so the result is `undefined`.  It can't see the `a` in the global scope because it is explicitly checking the local (`this`) scope only.

Clearly this is a silly example, but hopefully it helps a little.

Cheers

Comment: A property has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: can you explain further what you mean by what scope node is defined in and how to reference it properly? Can you perhaps give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: @Bergi Your blithe statement needs some qualification, because as it stands I can easily say, that's not true.

Comment: @Madbreaks: The [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), which has the "wrong" value in here, has nothing to do with variable scope. And `node` is not a variable either.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is due to the fact that you're using `this` as if it was in the scope of when the function `handleBtnEdit` was defined. The problem is `this` inside of handleBtnEdit is now a different scope (the scope of the `handleBtnEdit` function) and problem has no definition of a property `node`. Like was suggested above, a global var or storing the definition of `this` that you need could work.

Comment: @Bergi I did not say `node` was a variable, but it very well could be. And I'm sorry...if you feel that `this` has nothing to do with scope, you're mistaken.

Comment: @Fizz Exactly. `this`, here, applies scope incorrectly. Without more code provided by op it's impossible to say what the solution is though.

Comment: @Fizz - it is a pretty lengthy control script ( almost 400 lines). Would you like me to post it?

Comment: @Madbreaks: No. `this` is the context (correctly: `thisArg`) that is dynamically determined for a function invocation. And it has nothing to do with the static variable scope. Please read the doc I've linked above, and if that not helps the ES spec.

Comment: I have added the Add, Edit, Save and Form methods to my initial post. If you wouldn't mind taking a second look, I would truly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: so, now in the console log, it says this.getAttribute is not a function